# How to force React ES6 static method's "this" to be bound to lexical scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

In React (using ES6 via babel), I'm trying to create a static method that updates the state of the Component it is contained in. Taking in an obect as an argument. The problem is "this" is never bound to the lexical scope.

```
static updateList = (Item) => {
    this.setState({ cartUpdated: Date.now() }); //setState is not available
}
```

In the other component...

```
<div onClick={Cart.updateList.bind(this,this.props)}>Click</div>
```

At first I thought this may be due to the "this" passed via "bind" but I created a duplicate non-static arrow method in the component that contains the click handler and I could access lexical "this" just fine.

In desperation also tried making static clone of setState but no luck.

I assume this is a structural/security decision (if we leak out "this" we leak out everything!) but how does one handle access to "this"? Does this limitation force updateList function have to sit above the updateList and the Component with the click handler? This may actually be more react-like of course but I'm curious.

Comment: "*a static method that updates the state of the Component it is contained in*" - you're not making any sense. Static methods are on the class, there is no state. Do you want an instance method? Then use one.

Comment: If you could provide a working example of a method that can be accessed via an instance, when said instance is not found in the children or parent component of the calling component, that would be fantastic.

Comment: What do you mean by "*when said instance is not found*"? I'll assume `this` is your instance?

Comment: By instance I mean the React component from which I am trying to access methods. From what I know, unless I render the component and access its methods via refs, extend it, or inherit methods as props, I cannot access its methods directly.

Comment: For example if I did:
var Child = React.createClass({…});
var myChild = React.render(React.createElement(Child, {}), mountNode);
myChild.someMethod();

Comment: *"How to force React ES6 static method's “this” to be bound to lexical scope"* That's exactly what the arrow function is doing. It looks up `this` in the lexical scope. Of course in that scope `this` doesn't actually refer to your component instance because it doesn't exist yet. As already said, static methods operate on the class, not the instance. Your last example would work fine with normal methods if that's what you wanted. I suggest to properly explain the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The ES6 `static` keyword is only applicable to methods of a class, not standard properties. Thus, the assignment that you're attempted is not syntactically valid. One would have to write:

```
static updateList(Item) {
    this.setState({ cartUpdated: Date.now() }); //setState is not available
}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)'s documentation for a clearer explanation.

Comment: Isn't `setState` an instance method as well? Even if you re-bind the static method to something else, it just shouldn't be static in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried it with both an arrow and non-arrow function.  I believe I understand the distinction (=) but it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @Bergi you're right. I was just thinking purely in ES6 terms.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class StaticClass extends React.Component{
  static updateList(item) {
    this.setState({
      alert: Date.now()
    });
  }
}

class Cpn extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }
  
  render() {
    if (this.state.alert) {
      alert(this.state.alert);
    }
    
    return (
      <div onClick={StaticClass.updateList.bind(this, this.props)}>
        Click
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Cpn prop1="1" prop2="2"/>,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Seems to work fine. Well maybe things were different in 2015? Or maybe I misunderstand the question? Anyway, my test code seems to work fine.